# con't create new user in ASP.NET website administration tools

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

When I try to create a new user by clicking on 'Security > Create User' I got the following error message :
[image]

Also for creating a new role :
[image]

it identified the new user that is created by ASP:CreatUserWizard, so it is connected to database : 
[image]

Comment: Error said **Unable to connect to SQL Server database**. Is **Connection String** configured correctly in web.config? Could you able to connect to SQL Server via SSMS?

Comment: yes, I can, take a look at third image I'd included, I'd created a new user using asp:createUserWizard and it is identified by Website Administration Tool, so I think it is connectedto the DB ...

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

Thanx @Win, There should be two different connection strings, so I added :

```
<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=0.0.0.0,2012;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=DBUSER;Password=PASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and it is solved now.